# PHPMailer - E-mails tagged as spam

Tags: email, phpmailer, spam, email-spam

I'm currently having some troubles with some e-mails domain. Actually, when I send a message to those domain, I get this message back :

```
The original message was received at Thu, 12 Feb 2015 10:34:27 +0100 from smtp3.infomaniak.ch [84.16.68.91]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors ----- <person_i_want_to_contact@domaine_name.com>
    (reason: 550-ATLAS(2503): Your email was detected as spam. (RCPTs:)

   ----- Transcript of session follows ----- ... while talking to mx0.123-reg.co.uk.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-ATLAS(2503): Your email was detected as spam. (RCPTs:
<<< 550 person_i_want_to_contact@domaine_name.com)
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

I've been trying for days to find a solution but I'm starting to givin up... My PHPMailer code looks like :

```
function sendmail4d ( ) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->setLanguage('../fr','/language/');
    $mail->Host = 'mail.infomaniak.ch';
    $mail->Hostname = 'interpretercalendars.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'username_example@interpretercalendars.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password_example';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Sender = 'no-reply@interpretercalendars.com';
    $mail->From = 'no-reply@interpretercalendars.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Interpreter Calendars';
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@interpretercalendars.com','Interpreter Calendars');
    $mail->addAddress('person_i_want_to_contact@domaine_name.com');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Interpreter Calendars - Validate your account';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi,<br /><br /><br />Welcome to Interpreter Calendars. To activate your account and start using Interpreter Calendars, please click on the link bellow :<br /><br /><a href="http://interpretercalendars.com">http://interpretercalendars.com</a><br /><br />If your click on the above link doesn\'t work, please copy and paste the entire link into your web browser.<br /><br />We are happy you chose Interpreter Calendars. With best regards<br /><br />The Interpreter Calendars team<br /><br /><br /><br />This is a computer-generated e-mail. Please, do not answer to this message. If you need to contact us, please write your message to info@interpretercalendars.com<br /><br />';
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags('Hi,<br /><br /><br />Welcome to Interpreter Calendars. To activate your account and start using Interpreter Calendars, please click on the link bellow :<br /><br /><a href="http://interpretercalendars.com">http://interpretercalendars.com</a><br /><br />If your click on the above link doesn\'t work, please copy and paste the entire link into your web browser.<br /><br />We are happy you chose Interpreter Calendars. With best regards<br /><br />The Interpreter Calendars team<br /><br /><br /><br />This is a computer-generated e-mail. Please, do not answer to this message. If you need to contact us, please write your message to info@interpretercalendars.com<br /><br />');

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

}

Actually, depending of domains, everything works perfectly. But with the previous example, e-mails are allways considered as spam... Is there a way to fix that ? (Reverse DNS seems to be good and I've tried many different headers but not working either...)

Thank you and kind regards

Tidus

Comment: Could try using a third party service, which will tell you *why* your messages are being spammed? (It may be the content, or your domain is on a blacklist etc.) Here's the first service I found by googling, for example: https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: Thank you for this USEFULL website :) I've tried and returns me a 9/10. It says that "Your message isn't signed with DKIM". I'm going to check what it is and if correcting that the problem is solved or not. I don't know if that can make all my messages considered as spam... Thank you anyways :) Oh, forget to give you the link to my result, didn't saw it at first sight : http://www.mail-tester.com/web-rrWygX

Comment: One other factor is that you're sending to 123-reg.co.uk, which is top of my list for 'world's worst ISP'. Notice that even their spam rejection uses the wrong SMTP error code - business as usual at 123!

Comment: Wow, are they really so bad ? That sucks, I don't know what to do, people (with this ISP) can't register to the website and my customer is thinking it's my fault... Will try to contact them to see if I can do something (like asking them to stop ? :P). Thank you for this information :)

Comment: 2019 and '123-reg.co.uk, is still one of 'world's worst ISP'' . Exact error, randomly depending on what you have in subject, have that problem every single half year.

Answer (score 3):

To see if your setup has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.

Comment: Thank you :) here is the result : SPF check:pass, DomainKeys check:   neutral, DKIM check:neutral, Sender-ID check:pass, SpamAssassin check: ham. Looks good, but looking deeper I've seen this : interpretercalendars.com. SPF (no records)   +  spf.infomaniak.ch. SPF (no records) , does that mean I've a DNS problem ? Result for SPF is pass so didn't understood if I'am having troobles with this

Answer (score 1):

Your content-type and MIME-headers are missing. And I heard you should implement the PHP-version for sending mails, sometimes it gets marked as spam if those headers aren't set.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but PHPMailer automatically add MIME and Content-Type to message no ? In the source code of : http://www.mail-tester.com/web-rrWygX MIME type and content-Type looks well declared

Answer (score 1):

123-reg.co.uk is very bad service, it flag/reject as spam emails looking at text in your subject, and those conditions are extra strict, no names/email adresses/numbers/long texts in subject text.

Those who use 123-reg.co.uk as their SMTP provider will most likely get at some point to :

```
SMTP Error: Mailcore(2503): Your email was detected as spam. SA (RCPTs: ...)SMTP code: 550
```

I tried google SMTP to send same emails with no troubles at all.